# Coreplot iphone setting correct axis and crossover point

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I am using CorePlot for the iPhone. I can do a simple graph just fine. But what I'm looking to do is to have the y-axis go from 0-100 and the x-axis go from 1998 - 2007.  I'd like to keep this numerical (not custom text based labels) if possible.

The issue, is that when you set up these axis:

```
// We modify the graph's plot space to setup the axis' min / max values.
float xAxisMin = 1998
float xAxisMax = 2007;
float yAxisMin = 0;
float yAxisMax = 100;
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xAxisMax - xAxisMin)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMax - yAxisMin)];

// Modify the graph's axis with a label, line style, etc.
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;

axisSet.xAxis.title = @"";
axisSet.xAxis.titleTextStyle = textStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.titleOffset = 10.0f; 
axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.labelTextStyle = textStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(1000.0f);
axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset = 1.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
```

You get a graph that shows the y-axis at 0 going to 100 then the xaxis starts at about 1998 to the right. i.e. they graph does not cross at X: 1998 y: 0.  Is there a way to force it to do so? As far as I can tell I have to do a graph with x-axix range from 0-2007 and y-axis range 0-100. Then can I tell it to cut out the 0-1997 piece and shift so that piece is at 0?

The alternative is to use custom points. Which I tried. But is seems there is a problem where it doesn't show ticks on the graph line. For example if I follow the example in from the source, I can see 1998, 1999, 2000, etc but no | lines cross the x-axis. It's like the tick lines will not draw because I'm using custom lines.

Thanks for any and all help,

-David

Comment: I know about this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054727/why-wont-my-x-axis-show-with-core-plot-on-the-iphone 

I just need to move it in the X (to the left) direction not the Y.

Comment: If I just do this: axisSet.yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:150]; then it moves the yAxis to the right BUT the scene is then over to the right side of the screen and mostly invisible.. Not a real solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` property:

```
axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMin);
axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(xAxisMin);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer but the part I needed I figured out last night. If you just use one of these (y only) the view wont' shift over to make them line up. You MUST set the xAxis to a position (in my case 0) with the above statement. This locks the view. Then bring the left one in with the yAxis statement above. This will move them together. If you don't use both they will come together but the view will not shift to keep them in the visible area.